# SDL_Texture is not being set

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I am having troubles with SDL_Texture

RPGTutorial.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    bool quit = false;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("RPG Tutorial!", 100, 100, 600, 400, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Window couldn't be created" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if (renderer == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Renderer is not being created!" << std::endl;

        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;

    }

    SDL_Event* mainEvent = new SDL_Event();

    SDL_Texture* grass = NULL;
    grass = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "Grass.bmp");
    if (grass == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Grass Image was not found!" << std::endl;

        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
        delete mainEvent;
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }

    SDL_Rect grass_rect;
    grass_rect.x = 0;
    grass_rect.y = 0;
    grass_rect.w = 64 * 2;
    grass_rect.h = 64 * 2;

    while (!quit && mainEvent->type != SDL_QUIT)
    {
        SDL_PollEvent(mainEvent);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, grass, NULL, &grass_rect);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    delete mainEvent;

    return 0;
}
```

stdafx.h

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_mixer.h>
#include <iostream>
```

I have the Grass.bmp in the RPGTutorial->RPGTutorial->Grass.bmp
When I compile it, it is successful. It runs through the code til I get to the part where it checks if(grass == NULL) and it goes through that and exits. Can someone help me know why my grass is not being set to the image when I have the image in the same folder that the .cpp files are in? I even tried adding an Image folder to hold it in, and it did not work either.

Comment: Heya, it depends on your environment- some will set the current working directory to the location of the exe, some will set it to the project file. If you are using code::blocks that should be correct. You can test the mechanism by setting the path to an absolute path (like `c:\users\you\programming\....blahblah`)

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013. Would (c:\users\you\programming\....blahblah) work if I sent the file to someone else so they would test what I made?

Comment: Negative, you'll want to use relative file names if you're distributing your application. You can find your current working directory by using the `getcwd()` function. Then place your resources there. When you distribute your exe, place the resources in the same folder (or a sub folder).

Comment: I tried to use getcwd() function, but I don't seem to figure out how to find it. Is there an include that I need to add?

Comment: Yes there certainly is. [Check This MSDN Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf98bd4y.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the time, I recommend you take some time to go through the [Lazyfoo tutorials](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php) they are fantastic. He mentions this issue in the second tutorial, "Getting an Image on the Screen."

Visual Studio changes your current working directory to the place where your .vcxproj file is. That will be the directory you want to place your resources in. If you're not sure where that is, you can use the `_getcwd()` function in the direct.h header [MSDN Source For getcwd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf98bd4y.aspx)

Comment: This helped me out a lot! Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, if this seems to be the solution to your question feel free to check the little check under the voting buttons to the left here.